# Add a class to a background image?

Tags: css, list

I have a slider that is based on an un-ordered list. The way that it is made is to have a background-image, and then whatever text and header in the display on top of `<li>`.

This works fine, but it stretches the background-image, and using `:cover` cuts the image off. I have a great CSS workaround to use an image instead of a background-image, but then the text gets pushed to the bottom. I was wondering if there was a way to add this class to the background image

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Or... Can I style the list items to go on top of an image in this markup?

```
<li>
    <img class="img" src="images/sandpiperBG.jpg" />
    <h1>Fluid, flexible, fantastically minimal.</h1>
    <p>Use any HTML in your slides, extend with CSS. You have full control.</p>
</li>
```

I tried to add a `z-index` to the `<ul>` and the `<ul><li>`, but it didn't work.

Comment: it should be `<img class="img" src="images/sandpiperBG.jpg" />` (no `.` inside `class="img"`) to match with your CSS selector

Comment: Remove the `.` from the `class` name

Comment: and by the way, that's not a `background-image`

Comment: Pretty sure he's not showing us the markup/css for the background-image but for his workaround. Since he explained about `:cover` he probably had that working, but was unhappy with the result.

Comment: could you put your codes to jsFiddle and provide desired look in form of a picture?

Comment: that's correct. This is for the workaround, the . was a typo on my part. Apologies. I've corrected it. I will work on a jsfiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` controls what is on top, but it doesn't take objects out of the flow of the document. If you want to use an image outside the flow of the document you can position it absolutely and then `z-index` comes into play.

If none of these options works, your best bet might be to resize the image to prevent stretching or cutting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `IMG` to a `DIV` so that you can use a background image.

HTML:

```
<div class="myimg" />
```

CSS:

```
.myimg {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100px;
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('images/sandpiperBG.jpg')
}
```